# How does incrementing memory address affects pointer

Tags: c, pointers, memory, memory-management, pointer-arithmetic

I am seeking for an explanation regarding how incrementing an address affects a pointer.

I learned about how C pointers work and how incrementing a pointer is done by considering the pointer type. still I don't understand the following case

```
int main()
{
    int a[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    int *p = (int*)(&a+1);
    printf("%d\n%d\n", *(a+1), *(p-1));
    return 0;
}
```

I expected this line

```
int *p = (int*)(&a+1);
```

to make `p` point to the address that follows array `a`, therefore I expected the output:

```
2
```

**as it is simply `a[1]`**

But the output was *unknown_number* - **as I don't know which int is 4 bytes behind `(&a+1)`**

And the actual result is:

```
2

5
```

Why does it seems that `p` points directly to the memory sitting after `a`?

What is the source for my confusion?

Comment: Remove the `&`.

Comment: Another example showing that casting mostly never helps in C. Why the cast? It hammers away the warning/error the compiler gave you. Do not wonder ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two basic concepts:

- Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal used to initialize a character array in a declaration, a *expression* of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted ("decay") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`", and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element of the array.
- Adding 1 to an expression of type "pointer to `T`" yields the address of the object of type `T` immediately following the current object.  IOW, if `p` points to a 4-byte `int`, `p+1` points to the `int` immediately following it.  If `p` points to a 5-element array of `int`, then `p+1` points to the next 5-element array of `int` immediately following it.  This is how array indexing works - the subscript operation `a[i]` is defined as `*(a + i)`.  Given a starting address `a` (either a pointer expression or an array expression that decays to a pointer), find the address of the `i`’th *object* following that address and dereference the result.

So, if you have the declaration

```
int a[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

then the following are true:

- the *expression* `a` has type "5-element array of `int`" (`int [5]`) - if the expression is not the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, it "decays" to type "pointer to `int`" (`int *`) and its value is the address of the first element of the array (`&a[0]`).
- the expression `*(a + 1)` is identical to `a[1]`, and evaluates to the second object in the array (`2`).
- the expression `&a + 1` has type `int (*)[5]` and yields the starting address of the 5-element array of `int` after `a`.  The type of this expression is converted to `int *` and assigned to `p`.
- the expression `p` has type `int *` - subtracting 1 from this yields the address of the `int` object immediately preceding `p`, which happens to be the last element of `a`.

Graphically:

```
   +–––+
a: | 1 |
   +–––+
   | 2 | <–– a + 1
   +–––+
   | 3 |
   +–––+
   | 4 |
   +–––+
   | 5 | <–– p - 1
   +–––+
   | ? | <–– p (&a + 1)
   +–––+
```

Answer (score 5):

So in this example `&a` is of type `int(*)[5]`. When you add 1 to it it actually adds `sizeof(int[5])` - because that is how pointer arithmetic works, adding an offset adds the size of the type being pointed to times the offset. That is how you get `p` to be one past last element of `a`, after which you cast it to `int*` so now you have a pointer pointing to an integer at an address one past the last element of `a`. So effectively, subtracting 1 from it gives you the last element of `a`.

Comment: the key to my confusion is that I don't fully understand why &a is of type int[5]*, isn't &a simply an address? how does the language "know" it's a int[5]*?

Comment: @limitless: the compiler knows `a` has 5 elements the same way it knows the elements are `int`s: you told it. So it compiles `&a + 1` into machine code that will add `5*sizeof(int)`  to the address of `a`. (The compiler also knows what `suzeof(int)` is, so it can use the actual value of that expression.) None of that requires the information to be available at runtime, and it probably isn't.

Comment: There is no type `int [5]*`, it is a syntax error. You mean `int (*)[5]`

Comment: @AnttiHaapala thanks corrected, should have just written pointer to a `int[5]` :D

Answer (score 1):

You can manipulate the array `a` as a pointer to a int `int *`. But it is not the same for  `&a`, which is a pointer to an array of 5 ints : `&a + 1` will add the size of the 5 ints to the pointer.

Just remove the `&` before adding 1 to a, and it'll work as you expected:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    int *p = (int*)(a+1); // & removed
    printf("%d %d\n", *(a+1), *(p-1));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How is it distinct from comment?